# consolidate and remove duplicate MS excel

Tags: sql, excel

I have a large excel file with a lot of rows that are almost except identical except one or two columns.
I attached a sample to give you an idea.

Here's an example:

```
firstname----lastname----phone---address----email
adam--------smith-----0123456----123 F st --- test@yahoo.com
adam--------smith-----0256859----123 F st---- newemail@yahoo.com
adam--------smith----0123456-----123 F st---- test@yahoo.com
```

so what I would like to get is this

```
adam----smith---0.123456, 0256859----123 F st---test@yahoo.com, newemail@yahoo.com
```

[image]

Comment: Install appropriate software and get the job done (for example): SQL Data Quality Services or KNIME. If you want to do it manually, you'll have to do some rather fancy programming (depending on how far you want to take it): (1) Do you want to compare columns only if the first name and the last name match? (2) How about two different people with the same first / last name? How to differentiate them? (3) Do you allow for name similarities? for example `Peter Smith in 123 F st` and `Pete Smith in 123 F st`? Are they the same (due to the address) and name similarities? What about Bill and William?

Answer (score 0):

1. Allow your first row to be column headers
2. Select a row of data
3. On the data tab under data tools click remove duplicates
4. A text box appears, mark/unmark the criteria of which you want the duplicates to be removed
5. Excel will remove all duplicates except the selected row.